# Dynamics AX 2009 - Customising AutoReports

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have created a custom auto report (by clicking file > print - then modify to create new) with various fields but when physically printing the report, the first column wraps the text so it looks something like this:

```
Item #  | Item Name  | Qty
--------------------------
5439988 |  Test Item |  2
0049E
```

Other columns do not wrap text like this, is there any way of changing the column widths to stop this kind of behaviour so i can improve the aesthetics of the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `DisplayLength` attribute on the extended data type of the corresponding field.